# How do I standardize regression coefficients for use in a meta-regression?

Tags: regression, meta-analysis, meta-regression

I am trying to run a meta-regression, in R, using regression coefficients from multiple studies. The models from these studies tend to differ (Logistic/OLS/Weighted Least squares/2SLS). Is there a general way to standardize these coefficients so that I can include them in the meta-regression?
TIA

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the coefficients as the effect size then for this to make sense the outcome variable in the primary studies should be the same and have the same units. The predictor variable likewise. In the case you mention this is almost certain not to be the case for all four methods you quote which primary studies have used so I think you are out of luck here.